# Deriving intermediate trigonometric formulas in Euler's theorem

Tags: differential-geometry

Motivation:
The ultimate goal is to understand [Euler's theorem as derived in *A treatise on the differential geometry of curves and surfaces by Eisenhart and Luther Pfahler*](https://archive.org/details/treatonthediffer00eiserich/page/n141), and a trigonometric formula in a previous chapter of the book is referenced, leading me to try and work through that previous chapter.

Question: How can I derive or understand the last two equations boxed in red [on this page](https://archive.org/details/treatonthediffer00eiserich/page/n91):

[image]

This is Fig. 11:

[image]

and

$$\begin{align}
E &= \sum\left( \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} \right)^2\\
F &= \sum\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}\frac{\partial x}{\partial v}\\
G &= \sum\left( \frac{\partial x}{\partial v}\right)^2\\
H &=\sqrt{EG - F^2}
\end{align}$$

Comment: 15 is just the formula for the dot product. 16 follows from $\sin^2+\cos^2=1$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Thank you. That helps a lot.